# PUT method using drupal_http_request

Tags: 7

I need to update data in HP Quality Center with Drupal.

After login with success, I get some data from QC with the following code (simplified):

```
$headers = array('Cookie' => $cookie);
$request = drupal_http_request('http://qc.intra.xxx.com:8090/qcbin/rest/domains/' . $domainname . '/projects/' . $projectname . '/test-instances?query={cycle-id["' . $id . '"]}', 
    array('headers' => $headers), 
    'GET'
);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($request->data);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$testset_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

What I want now is to update some QC fields. For that, instead of GET, I need PUT. The code I've tried to update a test instance:

```
    $xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
            <Entity Type="test-instance">
                <Fields>
                    <Field Name="my_field">
                        <Value>my value</Value>
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </Entity>';

    $headers = array('Cookie' => $cookie, 'content-type' => 'application/xml');

    $url = 'http://qc.intra.xxx.com:8090/qcbin/rest/domains/' . $domainname . '/projects/' . $projectname . '/test-instances/404886';
    $request = drupal_http_request($url, 
       array('headers' => $headers), 
       'PUT', 
       $data
    );

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($request->data);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $testset_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

This is not working and I don't get any error also, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, looking at your code, `$xml_data` is instantiated but never used in your call to `drupal_http_request()`, you use the `$data` variable instead. Intentional or the culprit?

Second, your call to `drupal_http_request` follows the Drupal 6 (and earlier) syntax, what system are you using?

For [Drupal 7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x), it should look like this:

```
$response = drupal_http_request($url, 
  array(
    'headers' => $headers,
    'method' => 'PUT', 
    'data' => $xml_data,
  )
);

// this should reveal what was actually sent out
dsm($response->request);
```

Hope this helps some!

Comment: Thanks Stefanos. $xml_data and $data are the same, my mistake. About your solution, you missed a closing bracket in $response and I think that part has another error (=$request). Anyways, I tried and it didn't work. I can do it using external apps, like Postman on chrome but not in drupal.

Comment: So, to the second question,  is this on a Drupal 6 or 7 system? Cheers!

Comment: Drupal 7, forgot to mention that...

Comment: All right, so your function call is not correct, did you try the example I placed in the answer? Method and data should be part of the $options array (the second argument to drupal_http_request. Curious to see how this works out.

Comment: I get this error: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$request and I get a connection timeout error, altought I make the login request with success.

Comment: Sorry Stefanos, I was missing my domain name in my code. Damn, I removed it to put here and didn't noticed. Anyway, it's working now, I was able to change the value I wanted.

Comment: Hey, no problem. What still troubles me is whether the way you were calling the drupal_http_request the way you wrote in your OP was also part of the problem. Cheers